# Sharing only the public key Is secure?

Tags: security, restful-authentication

I need to secure a REST request knowing who is doing it. I know the HMAC method but I wouldn't like not store the client private key on my server. This is my approach:

1. The SERVER creates a private and public key for the client
2. The SERVER sends the private key and a client id to the client
3. The CLIENT stores its private key
4. The SERVER stores only the public client key
5. The CLIENT makes a RESTful request by encrypting its client id with its private key (ecryptedData) and sends the pair clientID:encryptedData to the SERVER
6. The SERVER looks for the public key of the given client id and decrypt the encryptedData
7. The SERVER checks if the decrypted data contains the same client id. If the client id is the same then the SERVER trusts on the sender otherwise it rejects the request.

Maybe this method already exists but I don't know it.

Is it secure this method?

**EDIT**

I reformulate the question:

if I care only about who is the sender and not about what he is sending in a monodirectional communication (CLIENT -> SERVER), can I use RSA in this way?

ONE TIME

1. SERVER creates the RSA pair key for the client
2. SERVER stores the client public key (I doesn't matter if the key is stolen..it's public!)
3. SERVER sends the client private key to the client

DURING THE CLIENT -> SERVER COMMUNICATION

1. CLIENT encrypts a known word + timestamp (to prevent replay attack) by its private key ex. SIGNATURE = encrypt(RSA, 'FOO:1234234')
2. CLIENT sends the message with the API KEY and singature ex. 54545345:SIGNATURE
3. SERVER looks up the public key of the given API KEY
4. SERVER decrypts the message with the public key found
5. SERVER checks the correctness of the known word FOO and the timestamp
6. SERVER rejects the message if the previous step fails

Is it secure this method?

Thanks a lot!
aGO!

Comment: Bad schema. Let the server generate its own Private/Public Keys (RSA maybe) and share the public key. On the other side to know who is calling your REST service try  a signature algorithm (El Gamal? RSA Signature).

Comment: Why it is a bad schema? The HMAC method too sends the private key to the client

Comment: Let's assume 200 client, 200 different HMAC key to generate and every message needs to be decrypted before the Server trusts the sender. With El Gamal the Server generates only its Key couple and every Client could generate its own pair too (if needed). So The receiver will be sure of the sender identity checking the signature of the message (and not the whole message). If you're using POST/GET/PUT verbs you need this schema to be sure. For monodirectional communication RSA will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

*"SERVER sends the client private key to the client"*: this does not seem very secure. 
If malicious clients intercept this communication, they can get client's private-key and can send messages as if they were sent by the actual client.
You should let the client generate the two keys, without sharing the private one.

Comment: OK you are right but every API service provider send back the private key to the client (Google, Dropbox, Amazon, etc). Beyond that, do you think the is secure enough for the goal?

Answer (score 0):

It's not secure to send a Private Key to a user. Please take a look at the next approach:

- The Client uses your or open-source (3rd-party) SDK (or crypto library) to generate a Key Pair (Private and a Public Key) - if you need, I can share some cool solution;
- The Client stores a Private Key into local storage (that key can be based on a Client password);
- The Client sends a request to your Server that contains his Public Key and some additional data about the Client (his Identity, name/email/etc.). This request will be encrypted with a Public Key of your server and signed with Client's Private Key;
- The Server decrypts the encrypted request, authenticates/registers the Client and his Public Key and signature. Here you should have some Public Key Management (Keys Service).

At communication step, the Server and the Client use their Private Keys to decrypt and sign data / Public Keys to encrypt data and verify signatures.